# How to access Unnamed namespace variable nested inside named namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++14, unnamed-namespace

This question has alreday discussed in the link
[unnamed namespace within named namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201023/unnamed-namespace-within-named-namespace) but no perfect answers were provided on how to access the variables of unnamed namespace nested under named namespace in case both variables are same

Consider This Code

```
namespace apple {   
    namespace {
                 int a=10;
                 int b=10;
              }
   int a=20;
}


int main()
{
cout<<apple::b; //prints 10
cout<<apple::a; // prints 20
}
```

Unnamed namespace `"variable a"` is always hidden. How to access `"variable a"` of unnamed namespace?

Is it even legal to declare unnamed namespaces inside named namespaces?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602334/how-to-access-to-anonymous-namespace-variable-if-the-same-variable-exists-in-glo

This link helps a bit... no definite answer again though.

Comment: @secretgenes Well, the answer might be: _It's actually not possible to do what you want, but legal to write that code._

Comment: @user0042 : then you should probably explain why not !!

Comment: @secretgenes Well, I'm all in. Needs some more research.

Answer (score 1):

> unnamed namespace `"variable a"` is always hidden. How to access `"variable a"` of unnamed namespace?

It looks like you simply cannot qualify an unnamed namespace outside of the enclosing namespace.

Well, here's how to fix the ambiguity:

```
namespace apple {   
    namespace {
        int a=10;
    }

    int getPrivateA() {
        return a;
    }

    int a=20;
}

int main() {
    cout<<apple::getPrivateA() << endl;
    cout<<apple::a << endl;
}
```

See the [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eba44b3d433b34df).

---

Though I'm aware that doesn't fully answer your question (besides if it's legal to nest unnamed namespaces inside another namespace).
I'll have to investigate what the [c++ standard specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) with chapters 3.4 and 7.3 a bit more to give you a definite answer why it's not possible what you want to do.

Comment: I know it can be accessed by making  different function names in namespaces, but what if the function name is also same? This is a workaround of accessing the variable of unnamed namespace. If there is no way to access it, shouldn't there be a warning or error message that it is inaccessible? Because it doesn't serve any purpose .

Comment: @secretgenes Not all cases of _shadowing_ will raise a warning. Also that's compiler implementation specific. And why should you give these (hypothetical) functions the same name?

Comment: unnamed namespace has its own scope , so it might be possible to give same name to 2 functions. And if I've to define function to access the unnamed namespace variable then i could've done it separately, without using nested unnamed namespace (by declaring int a inside 'getPrivateA function'). In that case unnamed namespace is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

I read this the other day and have an answer for "How to access "variable a" of unnamed namespace?"

I answer this knowing fully that it isn't a *perfect* answer, but it is a way to access the "a" from the unnamed namespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

namespace apple {
        namespace {
                     int a=257;
                     int b=10;
                  }
       int a=20;
    }

using namespace std;

int main() {

int* theForgottenA;

// pointer arithmetic would need to be more modified if the variable before 
// apple::b was of a different type, but since both are int then it works here to subtract 1
theForgottenA = &apple::b - 1; 

cout << *theForgottenA; //output is 257

}
```

Comment: This is true, but it's a hack(flaw in c++), you can even access all the private members of class.

Comment: Yes, gotta love pointer arithmetic. Anyways I was thinking about your question and thought I would add that it is technically a way to access it.

Comment: Although this is likely to work with all C++ compilers, the fact that a is just before b is not something you should expect... also someone who makes edit unaware that they should stay together... it's not a good idea to use such hacks in your code.